# Not inserting data form into database table PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've been trying to insert data from a form into a database table, but it seems like an impossible task. I've tried to follow all tutorials I've seen but so far nothing is working. Could you please lend me a hand? (ATM I just want to insert the data into the table, I know I have to work on this code)

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
    if(!$link){
        die("Conexion fallida: ". mysqli_error());
    }
    if(isset($_POST['enviar'])){
        $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        $nombreReceta = $_POST["nombre-receta"];
        $pasosReceta = $_POST["pasos-receta"];
        $query = "INSERT INTO datosformulario (nombre, email, nombrereceta, pasosreceta) VALUES ('$nombre', '$email', '$nombreReceta', '$pasosReceta')";
        mysqli_query($link, $query);
        mysqli_commit($link);
    }
    mysqli_close($link);
?>
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" name="formulario-recetas" onsubmit="return validarFormulario();">
    <input type="text" name="nombre" size="40" placeholder="Nombre">
    <input type="email" name="email" size="40" placeholder="Email">
    <input type="nombre-receta" name="nombre-receta" size="40" placeholder="Nombre de la receta">
    <textarea name="pasos-receta" cols="42" rows="10" placeholder="Introduce todos los pasos necesarios para la receta"></textarea>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar" class="send-btn">
    <input type="button" value="Ayúdame a rellenarlo" class="send-btn" onclick="rellenarFormulario();">
</form>
```

I'll appreciate any help you can give me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are there any errors? Make sure that you have activated error reporting in php. To activate error reporting, add `error_reporting(E_ALL)` in your php page.

Comment: You are pretty open to SQL-injection.. Try using prepared statements.. @AymDev OP is using mysqli?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $link you are using for database connection must have a name of database,
like this:

$link = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "password", "dbname");

For more information you can visit the Documentation on mysqli_connect(), here 
[mysqli_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php)

Comment: That was it! Driving me crazy...thank you very much!!